# How to display code output like mozilla development network using codemirror?

Tags: javascript, angular, codemirror

I am trying build an in browser code executor like mdn

[image]using codemirror & angular 6.

I am able to get the code from the editor but not able to display the result, like mdn ,instead the content is begin displayed in the text area

```
this._codeMirror.instance$.subscribe((editor) => {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = editor.getValue();
    });
```

How can I display the result(in this case `1`,please check the stackblitz link) instead of the the code
The full code is available in [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywjbnr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: They (MDN) redefined `console.log` to output result into element with `id="output"`. Source code is available, there are also some formatting utility functions. I don't get why do you expect output `1` if that code contains only definition of function, not called anywhere, it's not even IIFE.

Comment: I have got the solution using `monkey patching console.log`.Here is the solution
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywjbnr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

How about use `eval`

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = eval(editor.getValue());
```

and still need `try catch` to catch the eval error, and show error message;

```
   function test(){
      return 1;
   }

   test()
```

display the result `1`

Comment: eval should not be used due to security issues. Function should be used instead, look for more info at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval